# I always encounter an error when I try to use React BrowserRouter

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Whenever I create a React App and install react-router-dom, I usually encounter the error below in the console. I have tried watching

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Below, is the only code from my React App after installing react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import './index.css';

import App from './App';

import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(

<React.StrictMode>

  <BrowserRouter>

    <App />

  </BrowserRouter>

 </React.StrictMode>

);

reportWebVitals();
```

Also, below is the code I have in the package.json file. I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing react-router-dom but I am still encountering the same problem.

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you have attached apparently looks okay, Maybe you are doing something wrong in app.js. kindly share more screenshots for clarity.

Comment: Basically, that is the only code I wrote before I opened my browser console and found the error. I tried creating several React Apps and still encounter the same problem after wrapping my App component in BrowserRoute

Comment: Maybe you should try to uninstall react-router and install it using the following guide :  https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Comment: I used "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2"

Comment: I have used the following version :  "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",

Comment: Let me check by creating a new project on my own computer. maybe I'd able to find a solution.

Comment: I have created new project and after installing    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2", everything works fine at my side. maybe you try using the following commands:                               npm i react-router-dom     and npx create-react-app checkapp

Comment: try this `ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
`

Comment: This what I got trying to use the above `ReactDOM.render()` index.js:16 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.render is not a function
    at ./src/index.js (index.js:16:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1

Comment: npm i react-router-dom and npx create-react-app checkapp:  Those are the commands I have been using

Comment: I always create the app first and then from the app directory I install the react-router-dom. Could this be the reason?

Comment: try to `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` this then use above

Comment: I always create the React App first before installing the react-router-dom

Comment: I tried `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` and this is what I got `Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more:`

Comment: Or could it be the third reason? `You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`

Comment: bytheway where is your `react-router-dom` package in package file. i can't that

Comment: Try to `create-react-app` package globally by running `npm install -g create-react-app`. Then try `npx create-react-app my-app`. And then install router package again maybe it also the error.

Comment: okay, I will try creating the package globally. My react-router-dom is in another package file alone, the package file was created automatically when I installed react-router-dom to the App

Comment: @DSDmark If running an `npx` command there's no need to install anything locally (global or specific to the project) on the machine. In fact, it is generally recommended to ***not*** have any local installations of `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `create-react-app` package globally by running:

```bash
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Then try `npx create-react-app my-app`. And then install router package again maybe it also the error.

This solved the problem for me. Thanks, everyone